Running 'flutter doctor' opens Dart CLI instead of Flutter on Windows 11 Pro
I'm trying to set up Flutter on my Windows 11 Pro PC. When I open the Command Prompt and run the flutter doctor command, a new command window opens with the Dart CLI instead of the Flutter tool. Because of this, I can't run flutter doctor or create a new Flutter project.
The flutter doctor command should show diagnostic information for Flutter and ensure that my setup is correct.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
